# how to fetch & edit tinymce editor values which has a pre-set value in it

Tags: php, jquery, tinymce

guys im trying to get the user typed value inside of a tinymce editor, which already has a dynamically set value in it. the problem is im not able to get the edited values inside the editor as it returns only the dynamically pre set values when tested with alert popup. so what should i do to get the edited value inside the editor.

here is the code for the dynamically set value inside the editor:

```
$statusui_edit="<div type='".$updateid."' class='hidden_edit_4_session session_editor".$updateid." jumbotron'>"
            . "<a href='#' type='".$updateid."' class='pull-right close_edit' title='Close without editing'>Close X</a>"
            . "<input type='text' class='form-control title_s_edit title_s_".$updateid."' name='status_title' value='".html_entity_decode($title)."' placeholder='Title' >"
            . "<div>&nbsp;</div>"
            . "<textarea id='wall_edit_1' type='".$updateid."' rows='5' cols='50'  class='session_edit text_value_".$updateid."' wrap='hard' placeholder='whats up ".$session_uname."'>
             ".html_entity_decode($data)."</textarea><br>"
            . "<button style='float:right;' attrid='".$updateid."' type='a' class='btn btn-warning btn btn-large btn-lg post-s-edit'>Update</button></div>";
```

here is the jquery code that im using to edit the value of tinymce editor:

```
$(".post-s-edit").click(function(){
  var attrid=$(this).attr('attrid');
  var title= $(".text_s_"+attrid).val();
 var data=$(".text_value_"+attrid).val();
 alert(title);
 alert(data);

        /*$.post(
          "status/update_status_ajax.php",


        );*/
});
```

Comment: why was this question downvoted????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this:-

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();
```

for detail information: [Click here](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.Editor.getContent)

Comment: @gauravSrivatava thanks it worked  but how to set focus to the editor after posting???

Comment: you can try:- tinymce.execCommand('mceFocus',false,'id_of_textarea');

Comment: thanks again but im not able to still set the editors value to null after posting, using the above function and setContent('') @gauravSrivastava

Comment: how to set the value of tinymce editor to null after posting @gauravSrivatava

Comment: var tinymce_editor_id = 'my_tinymce_id'; 
tinymce.get(tinymce_editor_id).setContent('');